# Too many objectives on screen

Tags: starfield

When I play Starfield, I see 5 objectives in the world and on the radar, this is overwhelming.

How to get only one objective at a time?

Answer (score 2):

Thankfully there is a setting to see one or all objectives at the same time:

> Mission menu, read the bottom keybind. Swap it to "track active only". Menu should read "track all", if set correctly. Menu noted keybind is always the opposite selection.

[Source](https://steamcommunity.com/app/1716740/discussions/0/3824174193417863120/)

Comment: One objective at a time should be the default setting, anyway.

Comment: @TylerH I must have pressed the wrong button once, and then I thought it was a bug to see several goals on screen. While searching for a solution, I saw many people with the same question, so it looks like it's a common mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the setting to show only the active quest:

More then 1 target can be displayed if your quest requires it. For example if you have to place 7 gas sensors, you (should) get 7 blue dots on your screen.

Or if you have to eliminate the beasts in a cave, you will also see several dots, one for each target.